# Me = object (C#: This = object)

Tags: c#, vb.net, parsing, constructor, overloading

in short I just want to know, whether (and how) I can do something like `Me = object`?

(in C#: `This = object`)

The given object would be of the same class, just another instance.
I could not find anything about it in google and the forum search.

### Background:

This is not really a problem, but bothers me.
Basically I want to get rid of the init() function below (VB.net-like pseudo-code).

```
class foo

   ' init() is called by all constructors '
   private sub init(bar1, bar2)
       #do quite some stuff, initialize members, ...
   end sub

   ' heavy constructor overloading '
   public sub new(...)
   public sub new(...)

   ' a constructor that is supposed to parse a string     '
   public sub new(String)
      #do parsing, then call init() with the extracted information
   end sub

   ' a parser '
   public shared function Parse (String) as foo
      #do parsing and return new foo
   end function
end class
```

Now to my actual "problem". There are different ways to approach this:

1) I could call the .parse-function in the string-constructor.
--> the string-constructor will create the object foo1
--> then it will call the parser, which will extract the information from the string, then create a new object foo2 (by calling the right constructor with the extracted information)
--> foo2 is exactly what I want foo1 to be, so calling `Me = foo2` would solve my problem. But I do not know any way to do that or just "return" foo2 to the caller of my constructor.

Instead I have to call `init(foo2.information)` which then sets foo1.information = foo2.information 
So in short my constructor creates foo1, then foo2 via Parse(), then copies foo2 to foo1 via init() -->  inefficient

2) I could call the string-constructor in the .parse-function.
--> the string-constructor first has to extract all information from the string
--> it can then call my default constructor with that information... wait no... it cannot. This is because in a constructor I can call other constructors only in the first line of code. Therefor I had to create a helper-sub called init(), which replaced my generally used constructor. 
The helper-sub makes this a good and working solution, but I somehow dislike having an extra sub just for that single one case...

So this is absolutely no big deal, but it bothers me. 
Is there another way to solve this?

Thanks allot in advance, 
Janis

PS: Having a Parse(string) and new(string) is meant to improve the usability of the class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax:

```
this = something
```

is only allowed in `struct` types, not classes.

As such, the answer is no, that is not possible (since you're referring to object).

Comment: Thanks for the information, good to know. I accepted this answer, though I also consider earlNameless' solution as interesting.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to the question is: you cannot do it.

The solution to the underlying problem is below.

Make your `Parse` be private and return something that your base constructor (or `init()`) can accept.  Then call `Parse` on the one line you can call the other constructor.  I am going to use C# below, but the idea is the same:

```
public class MyClass {
    private MyClass(ResultsOfParse data) {
        ...
    }
    public MyClass(string data) : this(Parse(data)) {
        // nothing to do, the other constructor did all the work
    }
    private static ResultsOfParse Parse(string data) {
        // parse the string
        // put all necessary data into ResultsOfParse and return it
    }

    private class ResultsOfParse {
        // contains everything the constructor of MyClass needs
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this creates even more "overhead" than my own solution 2)
EDIT: (Did not mean to send it, just wanted newline...)
Though your solution is interesting as well and is another option to consider when having that kind of issues :)